# Swift access a list in a list

Tags: arrays, swift, list

`["list": Optional([Optional(["phone": Optional("+51263153765"), "name": Optional("Peter Agent"), "__typename": Optional("User"), "email": Optional("peter@pety.com")]), Optional(["name": Optional("Thomas Agent"), "__typename": Optional("User"), "email": Optional("email@gmail.biz"), "phone": Optional("+1313131231")])]), "__typename": Optional("CompareUsers")]`

How can I access the value of each element of each array in the [list Optional([..])]

So I can put use the value like so -->

```
let email: [String] = []

for contact in (the list) {
   email.append(contact.email)

}
```

and same for the phone and the name, if someone got a big brain related to swift please help.

Comment: Please include proper sample data in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let listDictionary = ["list": Optional([Optional(["phone": Optional("+51263153765"),
                                                  "name": Optional("Peter Agent"),
                                                  "__typename": Optional("User"),
                                                  "email": Optional("peter@pety.com")]),
                                        Optional(["name": Optional("Thomas Agent"),
                                                  "__typename": Optional("User"),
                                                  "email": Optional("email@gmail.biz"),
                                                  "phone": Optional("+1313131231")])]),
                       "__typename": Optional("CompareUsers")]
        
if let listArray = listDictionary["list"] {
  for data in listArray {
     if let personData =  data {
        if let phone = personData["phone"], let name = personData["name"], let email = personData["email"], let type = personData["__typename"] {
            print("User: \(name) of type: \(type), has phone number: \(phone) and email: \(email)")
        }
      }
   }
 }
```